# Y-axis font color using apexcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, apexcharts

I'm trying to create a candlestick chart with apexcharts, and everything seems to work fine, except that the yaxis is showing up with a very faint color that I can barely see.  I can tell that it's showing up because I can update the fontsize and see it, but for some reason the color won't update.  Here is my config:

```
export const chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    animations: { enabled: false },
    toolbar: { show: false },
    width: '100px'
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
    theme: false,
    style: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontFamily: undefined
    },
    x: {
        show: false,
        format: 'dd MMM',
        formatter: undefined,
    },
    y: {
      show: true,
      title: 'price'
    },
    marker: {
      show: false,
    },
    items: {
       display: 'flex',
    },
    fixed: {
        enabled: false,
        position: 'topRight',
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      show: true,
      style: {
          colors: '#fff',
          fontSize: '8px',
          cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
      },
    },
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      show: true,
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: 160,
      style: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: '8px',
        cssClass: 'apexcharts-yaxis-label',
      },
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      rotate: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I see:
[image: I made the fontsize on the yaxis larger so you can see this if you look closely]

Any ideas why this isn't showing up as white as specified?  I'd like to be able to show the yaxis values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version.  I did the following:

```
npm uninstall apexcharts
npm i apexcharts@3.6.3
--restarted npm
npm run start
```

Then it worked!